# My USB ports randomly stop working till a reboot?

Tags: usb

I have a HP Pavillion DV6-1149wm, Ubuntu 11.04.
I have 2 USB3.0 ports, and 2 USB2.0 ports.   If I use a USB port for a long period of time [e.x. with my USB WiFi adapter], that specific USB port [sometimes they stop in pairs] randomly decide stop.

After I've rebooted, everything's back to normal, but it is not practical to be rebooting all the time.

Here's `lsusb` [whilst only 1 out of 4 usb port work]:

```
matt: ~ $ lsusb 
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 0cde:001a Z-Com 802.11bg
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 138a:0018 DigitalPersona, Inc 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 5986:02ac Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Z-Com is my WiFi adapter,  currently plugged in to my last working USB port [until I reboot]. All other 3 of my USB ports don't work.  I plug in a flash drive, the light stays on, but that's it. Sometimes it will turn off about 5 seconds of being plugged in.  But when I plug it in, nothing comes up on the syslog.

Here is `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 1705
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Device 9647
00:01.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc Device 1714
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 1709
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 170a
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 170b
00:10.0 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:10.1 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB Controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5209 (rev 01)
```

One note, I will say that the USB device I use most is my WiFi adapter. [Long range wi-fire]  The USB extension that I use to plug it in is pretty old, and I've had to tape up the ends to keep the wire from being broken (from being moved back and forth so many times).  Could plugging in a faulty USB device cause the usb port to stop working, temporarily?

Comment: We'll probably have to see what's logged in `/var/log/syslog` when the USB ports stop working.

Comment: I agree with ændrük about info from syslog/dmesg being needed.  My guess is that a faulty USB device might cause this. Alternatively a faulty USB controller chip on your motherboard, or a bug in the usb controller driver...  (But it's all guessing without diagnostic info.)

Comment: Hmm.. ok, well next time it does, I will save /var/log/kern.log, ok?

Comment: To turn off power management on your wifi adapter open a terminal and run 'sudo iwconfig <your wireless interface> power off'. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the following in my search for info re the 'irqpoll' boot option...

> Add "[acpi=force irqpoll](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-usb-stops-working-problem-in-ubuntu.html)" boot options.

Somewhat contradictory to that, the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69936/kernel-3-0-0-is-not-recognizing-irqpoll-option) suggests using 'noacpi' instead of 'irqpoll' to fix USB problems.

Comment: add `acpi=force irqpoll` with spaces and no quotes, right?

Comment: Well I haven't had my usb ports break lately and yours is the only acceptable answer, so I've accepted it.  But I also haven't been using a certain usb cable that I'd been using before so I suspect it is probably the cord.  I should buy another usb extension on ebay or something.

Comment: @Matt:could you report on further experience?

Comment: @cipricus, I suppose it was just a bug with the linux kernel.  I am now on 12.10, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic, and everything I've tried works on my 3.0 ports! :)

Comment: I have similar issues on 13.04. Suddenly the mouse and keybord which are on USB stop to work until I reboot

Comment: @RockScience were you able to solve it?